# Replace every match but the first

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression to do the following:

I have this String: 123.45.678.7 and I need to replace all (.) characters from the second. The result will be 123.456787

¿Can anyone help me please?

Comment: We could but you have to try something first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code matches all of the periods with a regular expression, then puts the first decimal point back in the String.

Here are the test results:

```
123.45.678.7, 123.456787
```

And here's the code.

```
public class SecondMatch {

    public String match(String s) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String[] parts = s.split("\\.");
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            builder.append(parts[i]);
            if (i == 0) {
                builder.append(".");
            }
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "123.45.678.7";
        String t = new SecondMatch().match(s);
        System.out.println(s + ", " + t);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(
    "123.45.678.7".replaceAll("\\G((?!^).*?|[^\\.]*\\..*?)\\.", "$1"));
```

```
123.456787
```

---

This can also be done without a regular expression:

```
String str = "123.45.678.7";
String[] arr = str.split("\\.", 2);

System.out.println(arr[0] + "." + arr[1].replace(".", ""));
```

```
123.456787
```

Comment: Up-vote for meeting the regular expression portion of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function...

```
function removeAllButFirst(myParam)
{
  var numReplaces = 0;
  var retVal = myParam.replace(/\./g, function(allMatch, currMatch) { 
    return ++numReplaces==1 ? '.' : ''; });
  return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Note that OP has tagged Java, not JavaScript, for the implementation language.

Comment: Ah sorry - missread the Q - this is a javascript solution not java

Answer (score 0):

Just had a rummage and found this on the net - its fairly crude, but would do the job...

```
retVal = retVal.replaceFirst(".","$");
retVal = retVal.replaceAll(".","");
retVal = retVal.replaceFirst("$",".");
```

This does assume you don't have any $'s in your input - if you do pick a different char.
Its not great and there is probably a better single regex on Java using something like LookBehinds but I'm not a Java dev so couldnt say.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should also work:

```
String str = "123.45.678.9";
String repl = str.replaceAll("([^.]*\\.[^.]*|[^.]*)\\.", "$1");
// repl = 123.456789
```